# Calculating Large Powers with Modulus

Tags: java, math

I am currently working through something whereby I need to calculate the values of something like

(65^17) mod 3233 = *

The answer to the above problem is 2790, however because 65 ^ 17 is larger than the values that can be returned by Math.pow it always gives the wrong answer.

I have written an implementation using BigIntegers (and the built in modPow), but I want to avoid them if at all possible.

Is there an alternative way that avoids the use of BigIntegers?

Comment: Yes, there are a number of well-documented ways to do this without involving big integers at any stage. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation

Comment: The simple approach is to start with 1, repeatedly multiply by the base and perform the mod after each multiplication.

Comment: This reminds me the math course in school ....omg

Comment: Related, maybe even a dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8963686/algorithm-c-c-fastest-way-to-compute-2nd-with-a-n-and-d-32-or-64-bit-int

Answer (score 5):

if `x = y (mod n)`   and `u = v (mod n)`  then `x.u = y.v (mod n)` (where '.' denotes multiplication)

Repeated application of this is used to reduce 65^17 mod 3233,

e.g.

```
65 * 65 (mod 3233) = 992

65 * 992 (mod 3233) = 3053

3053 * 65 (mod 3233) = 1232
.
.
.
```

In fact we can shorten this because we have calculated `65^4 (mod 3233) = 1232`

So,

```
65^8 (mod 3233) = 1232 * 1232 (mod 3233) = 1547

65^16 (mod 3233) = 1547 * 1547 = 789
```

And finally,

```
65^17 = 789 * 65 (mod 3233) =  2790
```

Answer (score 2):

What Mitch Wheat's wonderfully concise but somewhat cryptic<sup>1</sup> [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16204661/139985) means is that this should work (pseudo-code):

```
   res = 1
   for i in 1 to 17:
       res = (res * 65) mod 3233
```

You don't need to use BigInteger at all for this because of the mathematical properties of modulus arithmetic.

FWIW, the reason that using `Math.pow()` doesn't work is that it computes 65<sup>17</sup> using floating point arithmetic.  The result of `pow` is too large to be represented precisely as a `double`, so you lose some of the least significant digits; i.e. the ones on the "right hand end" of the number.  Unfortunately those digits matter when you take the modulus.

---

<sup>1 - ... if mathematics is not one of your stronger skills ....</sup>