# Computation in Java doesn't equals to expected result

Tags: java, math

I am trying to implement RSA algorithm in Java.

When you give a look at this page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(algorithm)#A_working_example you can see this computation:

```
c = 65 ^ 17 mod 3233 = 2790
```

And when I use this Java code:

```
double valc = Math.pow(65, 17) % 3233;
System.out.println("Expected = 2790, computed = " + valc);
```

the results is:

```
Expected = 2790, computed = 887.0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: My first thought would be that Math.pow(65, 17) could overflow in Java... not sure..

Comment: ^ is not "power of", but XOR. Math.pow would be correct, but normal variables cannot handle such large numbers. use Bigint or something like that. Also, square-and-multiply won´t be done automatically (for larger numbers)

Comment: or this answer could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16204639/calculating-large-powers-with-modulus

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are assuming that floating point calculations are accurate to an insane number of digits, which they are not. `pow` is not the right way to compute `65^17`. You really want to do

```
65 * 65 * 65 ...
```

So

```
result = 1;
for(ii = 0; ii < 17; ii++) result *= 65;
```

Which will result in loss of accuracy (it has more digits than can be represented by a built-in type).

Look at the way that modulo calculations can simplify these calculations significantly. See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36318/modulo-arithmetic-with-big-numbers

It shows that you could do the above as:

```
result = 1;
for(ii = 0; ii < 17; ii++) {
  result *= 65;
  result = result % 3233;
}
```

There are more efficient methods than this - but this will give you the correct result.  See http://jdoodle.com/a/2l

Comment: Surely you mean `result *= 65`.  The loop you've written will compute 65*17, which would definitely remain accurate.

Comment: @Kyle I'm sorry it was a typo. Thanks for catching it. I was correcting it as you wrote your comment...

Answer (score 2):

Double doesn't have enough range for your calculation. Try a [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) like so

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    BigInteger valc = new BigInteger("65");
    valc = valc.pow(17);
    valc = valc.mod(new BigInteger("3233"));
    System.out.println("Expected = 2790, computed = " + valc);
}
```

Which outputs

```
Expected = 2790, computed = 2790
```

Answer (score 1):

double doesn't have enough bits (52) to exactly hold 65 ^ 17.  103 bits are required:

```
BigInteger.valueOf(65).pow(17).bitLength() == 103
```

Instead use BigInteger, which uses an arbitrary number of bits to represent an exact integer, limited only by memory:

```
BigInteger.valueOf(65).pow(17).mod(BigInteger.valueOf(3233)) == 2790
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `double` if you really need to manage real or rational numbers. In this case you don't need that. Use `BigInteger` and take a look [here](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/78crypto/RSA.java.html).

Comment: @divanov decimal was a wrong translation of my mother language ;-)